# How to convert a pdf document to xml document by python code (in colab)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

How to convert a pdf document to xml document by python code (in colab)

How to convert a pdf document to xml document by python code (in colab)

Comment: Have you have a look in the web?

Answer (score 0):

PDF Tables is an API used to convert PDF to XML, CSV or Excel. Try using it.

Visit https://pdftables.com/blog/pdf-to-excel-with-python